# Is there a way of customising the criteria used in Azure Speech Studio evaluation accuracy tests?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

Evaluation accuracy tests in Azure Speech Studio calculate the percentage recognition error by comparing the recognised text with the normalised version of the original voice file transcription. In some cases this results in errors where there should be none.

For instance, in the following screenshot, the recognised text from all five utterances *exactly* matches the original transcribed text. Unfortunately, because the apostrophe is removed during normalisation, the test fails with a high error rate of 12.5% instead of the 0% it should be.

[image]

Is there a way to customise the comparison so that the original transcribed text is used instead (in a case insensitive manner)?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-custom-speech-human-labeled-transcriptions#us-english-en-us) apostrophe can be substituted with the appropriate ASCII character as it expects human labeled transcriptions for English audio to be provided as plain text.

Comment: I'm aware of the need to substitute characters such as smart quotes with their ASCII equivalents (and do so). The problem is that in comparing test results with the transcription of the original text it is incorrectly using the internally normalised version of the transcription.